# Will Docker container be moved along with Google Cloud account transfer?

Tags: docker, google-cloud-platform

If Google Cloud uses Docker container that I pushed to `gcr.io` then it will also be transferred or will stay with my account? How does that work?

I am about to transfer whole Google Cloud account and not sure how to do it without harming my own.

Comment: Did you had time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem?

Comment: Yes, just got back to the computer. Thank you for providing the answer! Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If  you migrate your account then the old account will be shut down automatically.To your new account, all of your projects and data will be transferred. Your resources will continue to function normally.

Since there won’t be any changes happening to the resources available in your account, the containers which you have pushed to the container registry([gcr.io](http://gcr.io)) will remain untouched but for using these resources you need to enable the new billing account, for more information on account migration go through the official support [documentation](https://support.google.com/cloud/answer/7523192?hl=en#zippy=%2Chow-do-i-migrate-my-account%2Cwhat-happens-after-i-migrate-my-billing-account%2Chow-do-i-pay-off-my-last-bill%2Cwhen-does-billing-start-on-the-new-account).